# How to set default namespace in a .NET core 2.1 project

Tags: asp.net-core

I finally have the opportunity to play around with .NET Core in Visual Studio Code on MacOSX, but obviously a lot of things are different compared to the oldschool .NET Framework/Visual Studio way.

For starters I have not had any luck finding a way to set a default namespace in my .NET Core 2.1 project.

I have tried changing the project name in the .sln file to `RootNS.ProjectName` instead of the default `ProjectName`, but although the project name in Solution Explorer is reflecting my change, it does not set the expected namespace when creating new classes - it seems to only follow the folder name.

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "RootNS.ProjectName", "ProjectName\ProjectName.csproj", "{443D0B42-6E6C-4DC6-8E42-E90FFCEBD448}"
```

Am I too naive to even think this is possible?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I have already tried adding the `RootNamespace` element to the .csproj file like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  <RootNamespace>RootNS.ProjectName</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I use Visual Studio Code on MacOSX.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.localization.rootnamespaceattribute.rootnamespace?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is supposed to work. So it doesn't work in macOS VS? Have you tried in Windows VS or VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is going to depend upon the C# plugins you happen to be using with Visual Studio.  I've used the `<RootNamespace>RootNS.ProjectName</RootNamespace>` in the past but it did not work on both Windows and Linux for me. I was using one of the many c# Extensions plugins. Not sure which on.

I am using VS Sharper for C# plugin now. It has a configuration file called "vssharper.json" where you can add things like

```
{
    "namespace": "Answers.Hello"
}
```

That works for me in Windows and Linux. I'd try that on your Mac.